# strange issue in accessing elements that contains right to left text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting all the elements with className : "tickerFeedMessage"

if the first child of the element has right to left innerText I cant access it , simply I can't find it !!! , the loop passes over it !

```
var stories = document.getElementsByClassName("tickerFeedMessage");

       for (i = 0; i < stories.length; i++)
         {
                 personName = stories[i].firstChild.innerText;
                 //some work
        }
```

[image: right-to-left innerText]

### --------------------------------------------------

[image: regular english text]

in the first picture the element is not accessible (the div with class "tickerFeedMessage" )

but in the second picture the div is accessible! although it has the same class!

why ?and how to access it and reach the right-to-left innerText

Comment: Your two examples are not equivalent.

Comment: yes I see @epascarello , but the elements has the same class "tickerFeedMessage" , how to access the right_to_left text ?

Comment: No, you have a text node before and after. The second one does not. Add a text node, does it also error out?

Comment: `stories[i].firstChild` is getting the <span> element in second example. But in the first example you provided it's getting an 'HTMLTextNode'

Comment: @nanndoj what do you mean by HTMLTextNode ?? the person name I get in the first example undefined , how to get the text ?

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain how  to add a text node ?

Comment: Look at the first one it has `&lrm;` outside the span. That is the text node.

Comment: so I should take the second child ? @epascarello

Comment: You would be better off selecting the element you are after than relying on children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different situations and you problem is at `stories[i].firstChild`.

In the first example you provided the return of `stories[i].firstChild` is an `HTMLTextNode` element but in the second example it's a `HTMLSpan` element.

You may use `.children[0]` instead of `.firstChild` because the first will ignore textNodes:

```
   var stories = document.getElementsByClassName("tickerFeedMessage");
   for (i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
       alert(stories[0].children[0].innerHTML);
   }
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/93x0uo3u/2/)